# How to add test steps in a test case work item using Rest API - TFS2018 / Python

Tags: api, testing, tfs, request, postman

I am using *Microsoft's TFS 2018* and I have started writing some *Selenium* test cases using *Python 3.7* in *Visual Studio 2018.*

I have managed to use the REST API of TFS to return my TFS projects and create new test cases.

What I couldn't find is how to use this API to pass a list with all the test steps of this test case. I am not sure how and if you can add them in the body of the request as a string or array.

At the moment I am trying to make this work on Postman first and then I am going to try in python as well.

This is the request:

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://TFSLINK:443/DefaultCollection/TFS/_apis/wit/workitems/$Test%20Case?api-version=4.1' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic MYKEY' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json-patch+json' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Sample task 2"
  }
]'
```

Is there a way to achieve adding steps ? The API didn't mention anything about this.

In the response I get after creating a test case I get a section called 'fields' which should have included the steps but I can't see them in my response.

```
{
    "id": 731,
    "rev": 1,
    "fields": {
        "System.AreaPath": "TFS",
        "System.TeamProject": "TFS",
        "System.IterationPath": "TFS",
        "System.WorkItemType": "Test Case",
        "System.State": "Design",
        "System.Reason": "New",
        "System.AssignedTo": "Marialena <TFS\\marialena>",
        "System.CreatedDate": "2019-01-09T08:00:50.51Z",
        "System.CreatedBy": "Marialena <TFS\\marialena>",
        "System.ChangedDate": "2019-01-09T08:00:50.51Z",
        "System.ChangedBy": "Marialena <TFS\\marialena>",
        "System.Title": "Sample task 2",
        "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate": "2019-01-09T08:00:50.51Z",
        "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate": "2019-01-09T08:00:50.51Z",
        "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy": "Marialena <TFS\\marialena>",
        "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority": 2,
        "Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomationStatus": "Not Automated"
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://TFSLINK/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/731"
        },
        "workItemUpdates": {
            "href": "https://TFSLINK/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/731/updates"
        },
        "workItemRevisions": {
            "href": "https://TFSLINK/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/731/revisions"
        },
        "workItemHistory": {
            "href": "https://TFSLINK/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/731/history"
        },
        "html": {
            "href": "https://TFSLINK/web/wi.aspx?pcguid=07b658c4-97e5-416f-b32d-3dd48d7f56cc&id=731"
        },
        "workItemType": {
            "href": "https://TFSLINK/DefaultCollection/18ca0a74-cf78-45bf-b163-d8dd4345b418/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Test%20Case"
        },
        "fields": {
            "href": "https://TFSLINK/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/fields"
        }
    },
    "url": "https://TFSLINK/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/731"
}
```

---

I have tried creating this PATCH request to update the steps but it didn't work

```
curl -X PATCH \
  'https://TFSLINK:443/DefaultCollection/TFS/_apis/wit/workItems/730?api-version=4.1' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic MYKEY' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json-patch+json' 
  -d '[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Steps",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Test"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Steps",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Test"
  }
]'
```

---

And maybe this is a another topic but if the above is achievable, can you also pass the results after you run the test and update the test plan perhaps ? If this is unrelated please help me only with the test steps and ignore this question.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way to add test steps in Test Case with Rest API:

```
{ 
    "op": "add", 
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Steps",
    "value": "<steps id=\"0\" last=\"1\"><step id=\"2\" type=\"ValidateStep\"><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">Input step 1</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">Expectation step 1</parameterizedString><description/></step></steps>"  
}
```

For a few steps (3 on this example):

```
{ 
    "op": "add", 
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Steps",
    "value": "<steps id=\"0\" last=\"4\"><step id=\"2\" type=\"ValidateStep\"><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\"><P>step 1 \"Action\"</P></parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\"><P>step 1 \"Expected\"<BR/></P></parameterizedString><description/></step><step id=\"3\" type=\"ValidateStep\"><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\"><P>step 2 \"Action\"<BR/></P></parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\"><P>step 2 \"Expected\"<BR/></P></parameterizedString><description/></step><step id=\"4\" type=\"ValidateStep\"><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\"><P>step 3 \"Action\"<BR/></P></parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\"><P>step 3 \"Expected\"<BR/></P></parameterizedString><description/></step></steps>"  
}
```

Comment: This is working. Thank you very much. Just to be sure could you please paste an example of two steps so that i will understand what is required to send for each row (step id, step, expected). Also the type can it be something else or it is always "ValidateStep\" ?

Comment: I updated my answer for a few steps. regarding the "ValidateStep" I really don't know...

Comment: Thank you very much.. it seems like you don't need the `last` in the first step as well. i removed it and this works:
`"<steps id=\"0\">
    <step id=\"2\" type=\"ValidateStep\"><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">Input step 1</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">Expectation step 1</parameterizedString><description/></step>
    <step id=\"3\" type=\"ValidateStep\"><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">Input step 2</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">Expectation step 2</parameterizedString><description/></step></steps>"`

Comment: A bit unrelated but have you managed to send the test results as well to tfs? I will ask in a different question because this is solved but I was wondering if you can do the whole cycle using the API

Comment: Check this API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Comment: Thanks again. I will have a look.